# What should I do if the question is a duplicate, but I can find a new answer?

Tags: discussion, duplicates

An example:
[How to define a macro which does not read the next token after itself?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/207351/how-to-define-a-macro-which-does-not-read-the-next-token-after-itself), for which my planned question must appear here [Space after LaTeX commands](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31091/space-after-latex-commands/207358#207358).

What should I do to help OP and in the same time behave according to the suggestion of closing duplicates? I have thought that I should try to find a better answer, if he OP is not warned of possible duplication. But now I am afraid that I am acting against the rules.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If the question is a clear duplicate, mark it as such. If you have an alternative answer to the already-posted answers, add it to the list. By virtue of the duplicate, your answer should still have value.